How to add new entry to Gnome Desktop's context menu?
I want to customize the context menu triggered in an empty Desktop background, but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet; I understand one could achieve it with Desktop Icons extension and nautilus-actions plugin, but I have no need for icons on the Desktop and would just have a simple additional entry.

